# AttributeError in loading training dataset when using Mask-RCNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When using [Mask-RCNN-TF2.7.0-keras2.8.0](https://github.com/Kamlesh364/Mask-RCNN-TF2.7.0-keras2.8.0) for my test, I have some problems in just loading my training and validation dataset.

I provide my code here so you can better figure out what's wrong.

## Basic setup

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' # Avoid AVX Warning from using CPU
import sys
import random
import math
import re
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa
from imgaug import parameters as iap
from glob import glob

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath('/Mask_RCNN2.0/')

# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib

from mrcnn import visualize
from mrcnn.model import log

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)

import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU') # If there is any GPU available
for gpu in gpus:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True) # Allocating GPU memory
# config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.6 # Maximum consumption of GPU limit to 0.6  
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

# for visualization
def get_ax(rows=1, cols=1, size=8):
    """Return a Matplotlib Axes array to be used in
    all visualizations in the notebook. Provide a
    central point to control graph sizes.
    
    Change the default size attribute to control the size
    of rendered images
    """
    _, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(size*cols, size*rows))
    return ax
```

## Configuration

```
classes = {1: 'trout'}

class Config(Config):
    NAME = 'trout'

    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1
    # BATCH_SIZE = IMAGES_PER_GPU * GPU_COUNT
    
    NUM_CLASSES = len(classes) + 1  # background + number of classes

    IMAGE_MIN_DIM = 128
    IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 128
    
    IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE = 'square'

    # Use smaller anchors because our image and objects are small
    RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES = (8, 16, 32, 64, 128) # Refer to the setup in train_shapes.ipynb

    # Reduce training ROIs per image because the images are small and have
    # few objects. Aim to allow ROI sampling to pick 33% positive ROIs.
    TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE = 32

    # Use a small epoch since the data is simple
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 100

    # use small validation steps since the epoch is small
    VALIDATION_STEPS = 5
    
config = Config()
config.display()
```

## Dataset

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Value, Pool, cpu_count
import tqdm

def load_images(i, images, annotation_file, temp):
    path = os.path.join(images[i], 'image')
    img_path = os.path.join(temp, os.path.split(path)[0].replace('/', '-').replace(':', '') + '.png')
    if os.path.exists(img_path):
        height, width = cv2.imread(img_path).shape[:2]
    else:
        with h5py.File(annotation_file, 'r') as h5_file:
            height, width = h5_file[path][:].shape[:2]
            image = h5_file[path][:]
            cv2.imwrite(img_path, image[:, :, ::-1])        
    lock.acquire()
    count.value += 1
    print('Reading images: {:.2f} %'.format(100 * count.value / len(images)),
          sep=' ', end='\r' if count.value < len(images) else '\n', flush=True)
    lock.release()
    return (i, path, width, height)

def init_pool(l, c):
    global lock, count
    lock = l
    count = c

class Dataset(utils.Dataset):
    
    def load_images(self, annotation_file, classes, source, mode='full'):
        self.classes = classes
        self.annotation_file = annotation_file
        self.temp = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(annotation_file), os.path.split(annotation_file)[-1] + 'temp'))
        if not os.path.exists(self.temp):
            os.mkdir(self.temp)
        with h5py.File(self.annotation_file, 'r') as h5_file:
            for c in self.classes:
                self.add_class(source, c, self.classes[c])
            self.images = h5_file['annotations'][:].astype(np.str)
        np.random.seed(0)
        image_idx = np.arange(self.images.size)
        val_idx = np.random.choice(image_idx, image_idx.size // 6)
        if mode == 'train':
            self.images = self.images[np.invert(np.isin(image_idx, val_idx))]
        elif mode == 'val':
            self.images = self.images[np.isin(image_idx, val_idx)]
        else:
            print('Warning: set mode to "train" or "val", otherwise using full dataset')
            
        l = Lock()
        c = Value('d', 0)
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            with Pool(processes=cpu_count(), initializer=init_pool, initargs=(l, c)) as pool:
                to_add = pool.starmap(load_images, list(zip(np.arange(len(self.images)),
                                                            [self.images] * len(self.images),
                                                            [self.annotation_file] * len(self.images),
                                                            [self.temp] * len(self.images))))
                for (i, path, width, height) in to_add:
                    self.add_image(source, image_id=i, path=path, width=width, height=height)
                    
                pool.close()
                pool.join()       
    
    def load_image(self, image_id):
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        path = info['path']
        img_path = os.path.join(self.temp, os.path.split(path)[0].replace('/', '-').replace(':', '') + '.png')
        print(img_path)
        image = cv2.imread(img_path)[:, :, ::-1]
        return image
    
    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        img_path = info['path']
        path = os.path.split(img_path)[0]
        with h5py.File(self.annotation_file, 'r') as h5_file:
            mask = h5_file[os.path.join(path, 'mask')][:]
            classes = h5_file[os.path.join(path, 'class_names')][:].astype(np.str)
        use = np.array([idx for idx, name in enumerate(classes) for c in self.classes if name in self.classes[c].split(',')], dtype=np.int32)
        class_ids = np.array([c for name in classes for c in self.classes if name in self.classes[c].split(',')], dtype=np.int32)
        mask = mask[:, :, use]
        non_empty = mask.sum(axis=(0, 1)) > 10
        return mask[:, :, non_empty], class_ids[non_empty]
    
    def prepare(self):
        super().prepare()
        print('{} images, classes: '.format(len(self.image_ids)), *['[{}: {}]'.format(idx, self.classes[idx]) for idx in self.classes])

augmentation = iaa.Sequential([   
    
    iaa.Fliplr(0.5),
    iaa.Flipud(0.5),
    iaa.Affine(rotate=iap.Choice([0,90,180,270])),
    iaa.Affine(scale={'x': (0.8, 1.2), 'y': (0.8, 1.2)},
                      translate_percent={'x': (-0.2, 0.2), 'y': (-0.2, 0.2)},
                      rotate=(-45, 45))
    ], random_order=True)
```

## Load dataset (where errors occur)

```
dataset_train = Dataset()
dataset_train.load_images(annotation_file='/Mask_RCNN2.0/trout/Dataset/314_0_out.h5',
                         classes=classes,
                         source='trout',
                         mode = 'train')
dataset_train.prepare()
```

**The error info is as follow, and it seems to be circulating and can't stop even if I stop the kernel.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Mask_RCNN2.0\trout\FishSeg_0516.py", line 271, in <module>
    model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\mrcnn\model.py", line 2354, in train
    self.compile(learning_rate, self.config.LEARNING_MOMENTUM)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\mrcnn\model.py", line 2201, in compile
    self.keras_model.add_metric(loss, name=name, aggregation='mean')
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 1132, in add_metric
    self._graph_network_add_metric(value, aggregation, name)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 914, in _graph_network_add_metric
    add_metric_layer(value)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 765, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 3359, in call
    self.add_metric(inputs, aggregation=self.aggregation, name=self.metric_name)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 1113, in add_metric
    self._symbolic_add_metric(value, aggregation, name)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 1887, in _symbolic_add_metric
    metric_obj, result_tensor = base_layer_utils.create_mean_metric(
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py", line 35, in create_mean_metric
    return metric_obj, metric_obj(value)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 237, in __call__
    return distributed_training_utils.call_replica_local_fn(
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\distribute\distributed_training_utils.py", line 60, in call_replica_local_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 223, in replica_local_fn
    result_t = self.result()  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 124, in decorated
    tf.__internal__.distribute.strategy_supports_no_merge_call()):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.distribute' has no attribute  'strategy_supports_no_merge_call'
```

**My computer setup:**

- GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P620, 2GB
- CUDA: 11.2
- cuDNN: 8.1
- tensorflow 2.8.0
- Keras 2.7.0
- Windows 10

Loading dataset only takes a few second when I run my code on Google Colab (Ubuntun 18.04, run perfectly), but it takes a long time on local machine with the error message `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.distribute' has no attribute  'strategy_supports_no_merge_call`, and both CPU and GPU are almost out of memory.

I wonder if there is something different between Ubuntun/Linux system and windows 10 that I haven't notice? I have previously tested tensorflow 1.x on windows 10, and similar problem occurs. This really troubles me for a long time. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance for your kindness.

Best,

Erin

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The function call that caused the exception is nowhere to be found in your code, a quick Google search of  strategy_supports_no_merge_call gives me https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/1538, clearly this is caused by version mismatch, the new version is not backward compatible with the old version, you just copy pasted some code targeted at an old version and used it with a new version of the some library without checking the compatibility or understanding the code...

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Many thanks for your kind reply. In the end, I find that the keras version should be 2.7.0 instead of 2.8.0. I just follow [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53510) to solve my problem.